# Sort order by slug for looped child terms of custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, order, slug, children

I have page that displays multiple carousels that contains the posts for each child term of parent taxonomy: projects for the custom taxonomy: portfolio-categories for CPT: portfolios.

When Portfolio posts are added with a new portfolio category under the parent category "projects", it automatically adds a new carousel to the page for that child term.

It's all doing exactly what I need it to, however I want to sort the carousels alphabetically by slug. I have been at this for days and and I just can't find a solution that I can implement correctly with my experience.

I have also tried using various custom taxonomy sort order plugins however they have no effect on this page.

Any assistance to do either of the following would be greatly appreciated:

1. Get this code working with a sorting plugin, or
2. Edit the code to show the carousels in order of the child term slugs

See it at this link http://shakespeare-design.com.au/portfolio-gallery/

```
$post_type = 'portfolio';
$posts_per_page = 1;

$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type, 'posts_per_page'=> $posts_per_page ) );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :
    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy ); 
    $term_id = 61;
    $taxonomy_name = 'portfolio_category';
    $term_children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

foreach ( $term_children as $child ) :
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-left"> 
          <?php //echo $term->name; ?>

            <?php
            $args = array(
                    'post_type' => $post_type,
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,  //show all posts
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $term->slug,
                        )
                    )

                );
            $posts = new WP_Query($args);

            if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="project-carousel-slide" data-caption-1="<?php echo $term->name; ?>" data-caption-2="<?php 
            if($caption = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt || '' !== get_post()->post_content)  : 
            echo get_the_title(); 
            else :
            endif;
            ?>" data-caption-3="<?php 
            if($caption = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt): 
            echo $caption;
            elseif( '' !== get_post()->post_content ) : 
                echo the_content();  
            else :
                echo $term->description;
            endif;
            ?>"> 
            <?php 
              $tn_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
              $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $tn_id, $size );
              $width = $img[1];
              $height = $img[2];
                if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID )){
                    if ($width > $height){  ?>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('owl-landscape', array( 'class'  => "attachment-owl-landscape size-owl-landscape landscape") ); 
                    }else{ ?>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('owl-portrait', array( 'class'  => "attachment-owl-portrait size-owl-portrait portrait") ); 
                    }
                } 
            ?>
            </div><!-- .project-carousel-slide -->            

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        </div><!-- .owl-carousel -->   
    </div><!-- .container-->  
        <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```